# CSS styling BODY tag issue

Tags: html, css

I havent done any CSS / HTML development in a long time and im having some issues with styling the body tag using CSS.

What im aiming to do is have the HTML tag styled with a background colour, then styling the body tag to be 80% width and a different background colour which all works fine.

The problem is that the background colour only goes one screen height down then ends and I cant seem to figure out why!

My CSS is:

```
body { 
    width: 80%; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px
}

html { 
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100%
}

header,nav,article {                            
    display: block
}

nav {
    float: left; 
    width: 20%
}

article {
    float: right; 
    width: 79%
}
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

EDIT: After all the suggestions here the best result i could get with my CSS looks like this:

```
#content 
{ 
    width: 80%; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    height:100%;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;


}

html,body
{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;

}

header,nav,article 
{                           
    display: block
}

nav 
{
    float: left; 
    width: 20%
}

article 
{
    float: right; 
    width: 79%
}
```

Its still not doing what I want but this is the CSS that works best with the wrapper so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the background colour only goes one screen height down then ends and I
>   cant seem to figure out why!

Here's why:

```
body { 
    height:100%;
}

html { 
    height: 100%;
}
```

Ask yourself: 100% of *what?* The answer is *not* 100% of the content. Percentage heights always refer to a percentage of the height of the *parent* element. Since you have not set any explicit heights (in pixels), the browser uses the height of the *viewport* and calculates the height `body` to be 100% of that.

The *viewport* is the viewable area inside your browser. Since your content extends below this area (i.e., you have to scroll down to see it all), it ends up outside the `body` and therefore outside the background color set on the `body`.

If you don't specify a height for `html` or `body`, they will only be as tall as the content, but the background for `html` will still fill the viewport.

So the solution is this:

```
html {
    height:100%; 
    /* sets html to height of viewport 
      (bg color will still cover viewport) */
}
body {
    /* don't set explicit height */

    min-height:100%;
    /* expands body to height of html,
       but allows it to expand further
       if content is taller than viewport */
}
```

You don't need any additional content elements; the `body` behaves like any other element. Only `html` is a bit different since its background-color will cover the whole viewport even if the calculated height is different from the viewport or any child elements.

You may need some hacks to handle older browsers that don't understand min-height.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I think there may be some other issue here as I tried doing what you suggested and it didnt seem to help the problem

Comment: I just noticed that you have floated all the child elements of the body (article and nav). If you do that, body will no longer expand to contain those floated elements unless you a) float the body as well (in which case it will no longer be centered) or b) add a method to clear the floats. There are many float clearing methods you can find on Google. Here is a good one: http://h5bp.com/q

Answer (score 1):

This is the case because you've explicitly set the height of the body element to 100%; you only need the min-height attribute if it should always be at least one screen high.

I would also not resize the body element to 80% width, I'd rather use a  element inside the body for this.

Comment: Tried that but I just get the same results, I also tried putting everything within a Div tag and that seems to make the problem worse :(

Comment: I'm not being inflamatory, I'm just curious, I'd also avoid putting 80% on body - but why do you, I, and many others do this? Is there good reason to avoid styling body (and html) with layout causing properties?

Comment: Good question Danjah. I've managed to replace the styling on the body with a Div now after a little trial and error but im curious too about why we need to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a few issues:

Firstly, try swapping min-height and height because by setting height after min-height you are effectively overriding min-height.

Secondly, check your browser, ie 7 and below I belive don't support min-height, try w3schools examples to see if theirs work properly on your browser.

Thirdly, you may want to wrap your content in either content tabs for html5 (with ie hack) or in a div class="content" because ie. again won't display the body tag correctly.

Lastly, I'd set min-height to an arbritary amount for example 500px because 100% will just make sure it is large enough to hold the content within.

height: 100%;
min-height: 500px;

Comment: Getting back into HTML / CSS is trickier than I thought! I've tried your suggestions and it still displays the same way, setting the min height attribute in px does affect the background though so it looks like the height tag may not be doing what I want.  Also the browsers im testing in are new versions of FF and IE

Comment: Can I ask what you have in your content div? Could we see your html?

Answer (score 1):

Give the body only a background color and put a wrapping div around your content. Styling this wrapping div is the better way if you want center the complete content as set bodies width to 80%. The way with the wrapping div makes the round corner also easier.

An example of the resulting html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
.... Your content ....
</div> <!-- end of #wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: Same issue sadly, the background of the wrapper still doesnt go the whole way down :(